# Beginner | How can i use .jar and .so files from a library for an Android project (maybe NDK)?

Tags: android, jar, android-ndk, shared-libraries, biometrics

For my internship (compagny without programmation skill), I have to  use a trial library wich provides biometric algorithms from Neurotechnology compagny.

in fact the library contains .jar files. I added those files to my project and i used some class but there is the error : NoClassDefFoundError.

I supposed that i have to use the .so files which are also in the package from Neurotch. to definite class and method.

To do this, i installed NDK (with the Tegra android pack). But i never found tutorials on the internet that explain how to use foreign .so files to exploit those .jar in a Android Project

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use ndk. Typicaly so locations:
[image]